# angular/http not found on github.com

Tags: angular

I tried to install angular/http for using REST in an ng2-application.

```
> npm install @angular/http
 npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:angular/http Klone in Bare-Repository     '/root/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-angular-http-d5a38677' ...
 npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:angular/http Permission denied (publickey).
 ....
```

Whats the problem? I am sure its a rookie-problem but I do not see how to solve it.

My packages:

```
npm version
{http_parser: '2.7.0',
 node: '4.8.2',
 v8: '4.5.103.46',
 uv: '1.9.1',
 zlib: '1.2.8',
 ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
 icu: '57.1',
 modules: '46',
 openssl: '1.0.2k',
 npm: '1.4.21' }
```

Comment: npm: '1.4.21'? wow :D. I think there is a minimal npm version for it. Try upgrading to a 3+ version

Comment: Its standard for Debian 9. After "npm install -g npm" I get "npm: 1.4.21".

Comment: was working after updating npm. thanks!